# RSpec HaveSelector not working expect the way I expect when using Capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

Capybara's `HaveSelector` is not working with RSpec `expect` the way I expect. I'm new to Capybara and RSpec so I this may well be a misunderstanding of mine with respect to RSpec or Capybara, or it may be a deficiency in Capybara (version 2.0.2).  Please help me either understand my mistake or craft a bug report/feature request.

In my RSpec I wrote:

```
expect { click('.special-div .submit') }.to have_css('.submitted')
```

I expected this to be functionally equivalent to

```
click('.special-div .submit')
page.should have_css('.submitted')
```

but it is not. Instead, the matcher `have_css` tries to match against the string conversion of the proc object rather than the result of calling the proc object. (In other words, `click('.special-div .submit')` is never executed.)

Is Capybara's behavior:

- Quite reasonable
- An example of a missing feature in Capybara
- A bug in Capybara 2.0.2
- Something else?

Also, I can obviously do what I want by using the 2-line version above, but our team is trying to standardize on `expect {}`, so is there a way to use the `expect {}` form and get it to do what I want?

**EDIT**

I inherited the code I'm working with so I did not realize that, as Andrey Botalov pointed out, `click` is not a standard part of Capybara.  Seems like it should be, but then again `click` is already heavily used for other things so it may be better that Capybara doesn't add yet another definition.

Since some people seem skeptical, let me assure you that this code is working fine:

```
click('.special-div .submit')
page.should have_css('.submitted')
```

For those wondering about `have_css()`, that is RSpec magic for `has_css?`.  For those wondering about `click`, in my project, someone has conveniently created the `click` function as follows:

```
  def click(css)
    page.execute_script("$('#{css}').first().trigger('click');")
  end
```

Why? Because none of the obvious alternatives worked.

```
click_on('.special-div .submit')  # Fails because click_on does not take CSS
# Cannot use click_button() because we are clicking on a <div>
find('.special-div .submit').click # Raises exception because there are more than one
first('.special-div .submit').click # Fails because the div is not visible
```

Moving on, @zetetic asked if

```
expect(click('.special-div .submit')).to have_css('.submitted')
```

would work.  No, it doesn't work for us because we're still on RSpec 2.9 and that syntax was introduced in 2.11, but even if we upgraded it still wouldn't work because `click` does not return an object.  It would probably work if we upgraded to 2.11 and changed `click` to return `page`.

Comment: I don't use RSpec so I can't help in this. Please, try to ask about it in Capybara mailing list. You may find help from someone more knowledgable

Comment: Did you try this with `expect()` instead of `expect { }` ?

Comment: Capybara doesn't have `click` method in Actions. There `Capybara::Node::Actions#click_link`, `Capybara::Node::Actions#click_button`, `Capybara::Node::Actions#click_on`, `Capybara::Node::Element#click`. The last one is accessible only on an element. Probably you meant `find('.special-div .submit').click`

Comment: `click` returns nothing so I doubt you can write a one-liner for this in current Capybara

Comment: If you want to find only visible elements you should set `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true` or (in Capybara 2.1) provide option `visible: true` for `find`

Comment: @Andrey, on the contrary, I want to find and click on hidden elements.

Comment: @OldPro Ok. Selenium's click doesn't allow to click on invisible elements so it's done so in Capybara. (It was done intentionally as ordinary user can't click invisible element. It's usually adviced to make element visible as ordinary user will do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with `expect { click('.special-div .submit') }.to have_css('.submitted')` which is why I got so confused.

Most confusing to me is RSpec's `expect {...}.to ...` syntax.  I thought this syntax would cause matchers to run the code in the `{}` and apply the matcher to the result or something like that.  Seems to make sense given [the example](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax):

```
expect { something }.to raise_error(SomeError)
```

Turns out this is not generally true.  Only certain matchers expect the "actual" (what comes between 'expect' and '.to') to be a `Proc` and then call it.  Most matchers expect the "actual" to be an object.  So:

```
expect { 1 + 1 }.to eq(2)
```

raises an exception trying to compare a `Proc` to a `Fixnum`.

So Capybara's `has_css?` matcher is being completely reasonable in expecting the "actual" to be an object that responds to `has_selector?` rather than a `Proc`.  That was really my main question and with that, Capybara is off the hook.

Furthering my confusion was that Capybara helpfully provides a DSL so that in my examples  `has_css?` is equivalent to `page.has_css?` which led me to expect that `have_css(css)` would continue to magically operate against `page`.

On to the better way to write the test. @deviousdodo is mostly right, which is why I'm awarding the bonus to that answer.  What I wanted was

```
expect {
  click('.special-div .submit') 
}.to change { page.has_css?('.submitted') }.from(false).to(true)
```

Actually, though it's beyond the scope of the original question, what I really want is

```
expect { 
  click('.special-div .submit')
  page.should have_css('.submitted')
}.to change { Click.count }.by 1
```

The reason I want this is because what I want to check most is that the click gets recorded in the database (`Click.count` increments) but I have to wait for the AJAX call triggered by the click to finish, which is accomplished by `has_css?`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that rspec would not evaluate the proc, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The first part of the answer was wrong so I changed it.

I initially said that this code

```
expect { click('.special-div .submit') }.to have_css('.submitted')
```

is equivalent to:

```
click('.special-div .submit').should have_css('.submitted')
```

But this is not true because the proc passed to `expect` will not in fact get evaluated (you can read @OldPro's answer for more details).

The solution is to `expect change`:

```
expect {
  click_button('Button label')
}.to change { page.has_css?('.submitted') }.from(false).to(true)
```

You can find more details on the [rspec website](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change).

Comment: There should be `page.has_css?('.submitted')` instead of `page.should have_css?('.submitted')`.

Comment: Also I wrote in comment on question Capybara doesn't have such method as `click` in session so your code won't work

Comment: @AndreyBotalov I simply used his code, without paying attention, my bad. I've replaced it with the proper methods.

Comment: Actually, you are wrong, @deviousdodo; you are confused the same way I was.  `expect { click('.special-div .submit') }.to have_css('.submitted')` is ***NOT*** equivalent to `click('.special-div .submit').should have_css('.submitted')`.  In the latter case, `click()` is executed but in the former case it is not.  I explained this in my original post.